# Set up filters inside a package

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm developing a package that registers some filters which the user can add to their routes if they wish.

eg.

```
\Route::filter('myPackage.hasSomething', 'Panthro\MyPackage\MyPackage@hasSomethingFilter');
```

I'm just concerned where I should place these in my package.

At the minute they are in my service provider class under register. Is this a good place for them? Is there a common practice where these should go?

I've read some blogs which places custom filters inside a filters folder, the only issue with this is that this is for the actually filter method and not for the code that registers the filter with the router.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not place that code into your package as end user should be able to assign a custom name to your filter. Think the may have already another existing filter with a conflicting name.

Just create your package as normal, with the only particulariry being you must make sure you class `MyPackage` has a method `filter`. The end user then could install the package with:

```
composer require "panthro/mypackage:dev-master"
```

Then edit `app/config/app.php` and add the service provider within the `providers` array:

```
'providers' => array(
    'Panthro\MyPackage\ServiceProvider',
```

And finally add the filter to the bottom of the `app/filters.php` file:

```
Route::filter('hasSomething', 'Panthro\MyPackage\MyPackage');
```

For more info read the official docs [Registering A Class Based Filter](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters).

Comment: This does not answer my question. Where can I place the filter inside my package? I do not wish for the user to have to do it.

Comment: Then the answser is in the service provider.

Comment: Where abouts in the service provider?

Comment: Either the register() or boot() method, depending of the requirements of your package. It's all explained in the official docs http://laravel.com/docs/packages#service-providers